# Blocking access to all

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, port, port-80

For a server running Ubuntu, how would I make it so whenever a user tries to access a web page it looks like the whole server is down? It's running Apache 2.

Thanks

Comment: Umm ... why do you want to do this? If you block all users from accessing the web server, then why run it at all?

Comment: Well it's a VPS and I wanted to see how to make it so the web server portion is basically off. I'm new to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using ufw with the following command.

`sudo ufw deny Apache Full`

Or you could just turn off apache

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop`

Comment: The former of those will only work if ufw is enabled. And the more Ubuntu-ish way to do the latter is: service apache2 stop